# How can I accomplish type narrowing even if the narrowing logic is extracted elsewhere?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to conditionally render a react component `TransactionSummary` which requires `paymentSetup` to be defined.

Edit: `paymentSetup` is a value of type `PaymentSetupType` | `null` which is required by `TransactionSummary`.

I've extracted the conditional logic as follows to keep the code clean.

```
const canShowTransactionSummary = Boolean(paymentSetup && several_other_conditions);

return (
   canShowTransactionSummary && 
   <TransactionSummary paymentSetup={paymentSetup} ...non_relevant_props />
)
```

It is possible for `paymentSetup` to be null and I've excluded this possibility by calculating `canShowTransactionSummary`. However, I still see a TS warning -

```
type 'PaymentSetupType | null' is not assignable to type 'PaymentSetupType'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'PaymentSetupType'.
```

I can resolve this by either

a. including the conditions directly before `TransactionSummary ...`
(which I want to avoid in order to keep the code clean) or
b. by using
a type annotation (not a preferred option either)

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Edit: Simplified code for `TransactionSummary` is below. Only `paymentSetup` is a relevant prop for our discussion.

```
type PaymentSetupType {
  unitCost: number;
  // other properties (not important)
}

interface Props {
  currency: string;
  quantity: number;
  paymentSetup: PaymentSetupType;
}

const TransactionSummary = ({
  currency,
  quantity,
  paymentSetup,
}: Props): ReactElement => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <div>
      Donating 
        {getFormatedCurrency(
          i18n.language,
          currency,
          paymentSetup.unitCost * quantity
        )} for {quantity} trees
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code. What is `PaymentSetupType?`

Comment: You will need to rewrite the code in one way or another. But since you're not showing the actual code, it's hard to suggest what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructing a `Boolean`, an explicit null check will successfully narrow the type:

```
type PaymentSetupType = {};

const paymentSetup = Math.random() < .5 ? {} : null;
const canShowTransactionSummary = paymentSetup != null;

if (canShowTransactionSummary) {
  fn(paymentSetup); // no error
}

function fn(paymentSetup: PaymentSetupType) {}
```

TypeScript jsut doesn't seem to deal well with making inferences based on the result of that `Boolean` constructor. Even just a standard *truthy* check would successfully narrow the type:

```
if (paymentSetup) {
  fn(paymentSetup); // no error
}
```

On a side note, you mention you're trying to keep the code clean, but neither casting potential null values to `Boolean`, nor using short-circuit boolean operators to control program flow are the hallmarks of clean code.

Comment: Didn't know that about TS inferences not working very well with `Boolean`. That helps.

How would you avoid using short-circuit boolean operators to evaluate a large number of conditions? Or do you just mean making sure that each condition separately evaluates to a boolean value.

Comment: I'm not arguing against short-circuit boolean evaluation in itself, but expressions in the form of `condition && doSomeAction()` are a lot harder to read than `if (condition) doSomeAction()`.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76269118/how-can-i-accomplish-type-narrowing-even-if-the-narrowing-logic-is-extracted-els#comment134497518_76269391) @mohitb See this example: https://tsplay.dev/mblE4w

Comment: @jsejcksn Better to use a non-strict comparison (`!=` instead of `!==`) for `null`. It also eliminates `undefined` values.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'd agree with this if it's just a couple of `if` statements. However, if I'm creating a parent component which conditionally shows a number of child components, I find multiple `if` statements harder to read than 

`{ canShowComponent1 && <Component1 /> }`
`{ canShowComponent2 && <Component2 /> }`.

May be a personal choice though.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76269118/how-can-i-accomplish-type-narrowing-even-if-the-narrowing-logic-is-extracted-els/76269391?noredirect=1#comment134497763_76269391) @RobbyCornelissen In [generalized abstractions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70931345/438273): of course — but that's not relevant to this code. 

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76269118/how-can-i-accomplish-type-narrowing-even-if-the-narrowing-logic-is-extracted-els/76269391?noredirect=1#comment134497795_76269391) @mohitb No, that's not a broadly applicable pattern in React because of [caveats](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored) — e.g. if the first variable is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), but happens to be something like `0` or `""`, it will be rendered as-is in the vDOM — which is almost never the desired behavior.

Comment: Using `someCondition && <SomeComponent>` inside JSX is perfectly fine and readable, it has nothing to do with short-circuiting like `someCondition && doSomeAction()` where the second part has side effects. And the caveats about 0 and the empty string being falsy is also irrelevant, you should not use numbers or strings as boolean conditions to begin with.